# Link Keyframes to Markers

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

Is it possible to link Keyframes to Markers?

I'm at the point of creating more complicated animations and have created a number of Markers at key points in the timeline. It would seem logical to me to be able to link keyframes to markers so that moving a marker would automatically move the associated keyframes relative to the associated markers - for example, if one keyframe was 25% of the way between two associated markers then moving one of the marks could rescale the associated keyframes so that they remain at 25% of the way between the new positions of the markers. Is this possible?

I know I can select the keyframes in the dopesheet and move/scale them from there but moving markers and having them move/scale automatically would seem somehow more logical. Or is there a better way?

Comment: Did you try NLA Editor to edit animations?

Comment: @Jerryno I've not really used the NLA Editor much - it (and actions) always confused me so I've never really got around to playing around with it much. In my mind Marker would be able to be 'hooked' to keyframes to scale them just by moving the markers - but now I guess they are only really useful as labels though...?

Comment: They are only labels, yes. An action is just a holder for keyframes, and in NLA editor you can layer and scale and adjust those actions into animations. So instead of having one action with markers labeling sections of the whole animation have multiple actions each representing every animation section. Then layer and time those actions in NLA editor into the final animation. You can edit an NLA strip by hitting TAB - it will show in Dopesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage - no. A marker can be linked to a camera as a way to change the active camera during an animation but there is no link between markers and keyframes, it is not possible to move both markers and keyframes at the same time.

It would be possible to [create an addon](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) that would allow you to move markers and keyframes at the same time.

Comment: Seems that this addon is doing exactly that: https://blendermarket.com/products/key-to-marker